# How to call Rest API in angular

Tags: angular, rest

The Rest API consumes JSON input as below and produces JSON response.

```
    {
       "addressObject":{
       "streetAddressLine": "abc",
       "city": "xyz" ,
       "state": "ghi" ,
       "zip" : "123"
       }
    }
```

I have a angular project with below code in app.component.html:

```
    <input type="text" name="streetAddressLine">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="text" name="state">
    <input type="text" name="zip">
    <input type="submit" value="Execute">
```

After filling above details whenever i click on 'Execute', my angular application should make a call to Rest API and pass above data as JSON input to the Rest API. How to implement this?

I am new to Angular.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There are a variety of Angular tutorials available online that can help you.  Making HTTP AJAX calls is covered by many, if not all, such tutorials.  You are encouraged to start with some introductory materials on Angular and make an attempt.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David Can u please share the link to the Angular tutorial from which i will be able to implement the above?

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+tutorial)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this Tutorial, it teaches CRUD operations in Angular. [Angular CRUD](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-11-crud-rest-api-tutorial/). It is beginner friendly too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).